# Need some help with XML parsing

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The XML feed is located at: http://xml.betclick.com/odds_fr.xml

I need a php loop to echo the name of the match, the hour, and the bets options and the odds links.
The function will select and display ONLY the matchs of the day with streaming="1" and the bets type "Ftb_Mr3".

I'm new to xpath and simplexml.

Thanks in advance.

So far I have:

```
<?php
$xml_str = file_get_contents("http://xml.betclick.com/odds_fr.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

// need xpath magic
$xml->xpath();

// display

?>
```

Comment: And what have you come up with so far?

Comment: once I get the xpath figure out i'll be able to loop it.

<?php
$xml_str = file_get_contents($"http://xml.betclick.com/odds_fr.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

// need xpath magic
$xml->xpath();

// display

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xpath is pretty simple once you get the hang of it

you basically want to get every match tag with a certain attribute

```
//match[@streaming=1]
```

will work pefectly, it gets every match tag from underneath the parent tag with the attribute streaming equal to 1

And i just realised you also want matches with a bets type of "Ftb_Mr3"

```
//match[@streaming=1]/bets/bet[@code="Ftb_Mr3"]
```

This will return the bet node though, we want the match, which we know is the grandparent

```
//match[@streaming=1]/bets/bet[@code="Ftb_Mr3"]/../..
```

the two dots work like they do in file paths, and gets the match.

now to work this into your sample just change the final bit to

```
// need xpath magic
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//match[@streaming=1]/bets/bet[@code="Ftb_Mr3"]/../..');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

to print all the match names.

Comment: Hey, that's cool, and it makes sense. Thanks! I love w3schools, but those sorts of examples, for me, just usually don't make sense until I see a practical one like the poster above and your example for it. It's weird, but it's just the way I learn. Drives me nuts sometimes because a lot of people think you're not a good programmer if you don't learn the same way as everyone else. Anyway, not to rant, but I'm a bit dyslexic, so it's much easier to talk about something for me as a kick start. Somehow, after that, it's like a key unlocks something and I can get into the 'standard' references.

Comment: That XPath expression should really be `//match[@streaming = "1"][bets/bet/@code = "Ftb_Mr3"]` -- the node you're looking for is "match" and the rest are predicates, they should be treated as such

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to work xpath really, but if you want to 'loop it', this should get you started:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("odds_fr.xml");

  foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
  {
    foreach ($child->children() as $child2)
    {
      foreach ($child2->children() as $child3)
      {
        foreach($child3->attributes() as $a => $b)
        {
          echo $a,'="',$b,"\"</br>";
        }

      }
    }
  }
?>
```

That gets you to the 'match' tag which has the 'streaming' attribute. I don't really know what 'matches of the day' are, either, but...

It's basically right out of the w3c reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ref_simplexml.asp

Comment: Read my other comment. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on a project. Scraping Beclic odds with:

```
<?php
        $match_csv = fopen('matches.csv', 'w');
        $bet_csv = fopen('bets.csv', 'w');
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.cdn.betclic.com/odds_en.xml');
        $bookmaker = 'Betclick';
        foreach ($xml as $sport) {
            $sport_name = $sport->attributes()->name;
            foreach ($sport as $event) {
                $event_name = $event->attributes()->name;
                foreach ($event as $match) {
                    $match_name = $match->attributes()->name;
                    $match_id = $match->attributes()->id;
                    $match_start_date_str = str_replace('T', ' ', $match->attributes()->start_date);
                    $match_start_date = strtotime($match_start_date_str);
                    if (!empty($match->attributes()->live_id)) {
                        $match_is_live = 1;
                    } else {
                        $match_is_live = 0;
                    }
                    if ($match->attributes()->streaming == 1) {
                        $match_is_running = 1;
                    } else {
                        $match_is_running = 0;
                    }
                    $match_row = $match_id . ',' . $bookmaker . ',' . $sport_name . ',' . $event_name . ',' . $match_name . ',' . $match_start_date . ',' . $match_is_live . ',' . $match_is_running;
                    fputcsv($match_csv, explode(',', $match_row));
                    foreach ($match as $bets) {
                        foreach ($bets as $bet) {
                            $bet_name = $bet->attributes()->name;
                            foreach ($bet as $choice) {
                                // team numbers are surrounded by %, we strip them
                                $choice_name = str_replace('%', '', $choice->attributes()->name);
                                // get the float value of odss
                                $odd = (float)$choice->attributes()->odd;
                                // concat the row to be put to csv file
                                $bet_row = $match_id . ',' . $bet_name . ',' . $choice_name . ',' . $odd;
                                fputcsv($bet_csv, explode(',', $bet_row));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($match_csv);
        fclose($bet_csv);
?>
```

Then loading the csv files into mysql. Running it once a minute, works great so far.